# Is there a page length limit?

Tags: mysql, content

I am developing a site and it has 4k lines of content for some of the page (this is when you view source). It is in WordPress, however, I can't seem to add anymore content. It doesn't even respond when I want to add a media.

This site is not a regular website, so I fear I should be using Drupal due to the size issue.

Is there a size issue in WordPress? (I am using WordPress version 4.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

The post content field is MySQL type `longtext`, which has a limit of 4 gigabytes.

What you may be encountering is an issue with the [TinyMCE editor](http://www.tinymce.com/). Content is processed and validated in the browser with JavaScript. If that's the case, I doubt you will improve your situation by using Drupal, since you will be using some sort of JavaScript-driven editor in that case as well.

You should perhaps reconsider how you are structuring your content.